# Query to select distinct pairs of value from one column in a table and distinct value from another column in another table

Tags: sql-server, redshift

**Table A**

| Col 1 | Col 2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | B |
| C | D |

**Table B**

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| E | F |
| G | H |

**Expected Output**

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | E |
| B | G |

They should be distinct in each of the column of combined table, it should not be: (A, E) and (A, G), or (B, E) and (B, G). Because A is already used with E and B is already used with G.

Comment: How/why A and B, values from different columns end up in the same column in the result? Is that a typo or wanted?

Comment: Also: is the question for SQL Server or Redshift? And which versions? These are different RDBMS  and different queries may be required.

Comment: Can you format your table examples please?

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).